# Python loop over values in dataframe and change to binary values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a series `y` in Python with values `Accepted` and `Rejected`. I want to create a new dataframe with value **1** for `Accepted` and **0** for `Rejected`.

I'm trying to loop through the values of `y` and write to a new df `dummy`. My progress so far is

```
dummy=pd.DataFrame()
i=0

for i in range(0,len(y)):
    if y[i]=='Approved': 
        dummy[i:]==1
    else: 
        dummy[i:]==0
```

but I got a feeling that I'm off track. Can anyone help me out?

The series `y` looks like this:

```
   y
Accepted
Rejected
Accepted
Accepted
Accepted
```

The desired output should be something like

```
dummy
  1
  0
  1
  1
  1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here loop is not necessary, because slow. Better is convert boolean mask to `True/False` to `0,1` by converting to `integer`s or use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['dummy'] =  (df['y']=='Approved').astype(int)
```

---

```
df['dummy'] =  np.where(df['y']=='Approved', 1, 0)
```

---

Your solution should be changed (loopy slow solution):

```
print (df)

0  Accepted
1  Rejected
2  Accepted
3  Accepted
4  Accepted

out = []
for i in range(0,len(df)):
    if df.loc[i, 'y']=='Accepted': 
        out.append(1)
    else: 
        out.append(0)

print (out)
[1, 0, 1, 1, 1]

df['dummy'] = out
print (df)
          y  dummy
0  Accepted      1
1  Rejected      0
2  Accepted      1
3  Accepted      1
4  Accepted      1
```

Comment: @Artem - yes, added to answer.

Answer (score 1):

you can use:

```
df['dummy'] = df.y.apply(lambda x:  1 if  x == 'Accepted' else 0)
```

if you want to use a for loop:

```
new_dummy_data = []

for value in df.y.values:
    if value == 'Accepted':
        new_dummy_data.append(1)
    else:
        new_dummy_data.append(0)

df['dummy'] = new_dummy_data
```

Comment: apply is loop under the hood ;)

Comment: yep, but  not in the way the OP wants,  I mean a visible for loop